# Difference between "fun1 arg |> fun2" and "fun1(arg) |> fun2" in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I've been trying some simple keyboard IO in Elixir, mainly in IO module. `IO.puts` is quite handy as in its most basic form, it prints a prompt and waits for a string to be typed.

I've run into some strange behavior; "strange" because I can't figure out what is really going on. Here comes the `iex` session  along with the comments and questions:

```
iex(85)> IO.gets "Your name: "    
Your name: polo
"polo\n"
```

So far so good

```
iex(86)> IO.gets "Your name: " |> String.trim
Your name:polo
"polo\n"
```

First notice that `polo` is not anymore separated by a space from the prompt  like previously. Moreover, the `trim` function does not to apply as I get the `\n` at the end of the string.

Now, if I type:

```
iex(87)> String.trim(IO.gets "Your name: ")  
Your name: polo
"polo"
```

everything seems to come back to the normal behavior: the space in the prompt is here and the input is trim-ed as expected.

Eventually I remembered reading in a book (or was it a blog?) that there was some slight difference between both syntaxes, so I tried:

```
iex(88)> IO.gets("Your name: ") |> String.trim
Your name: polo
"polo"
```

and bingo!

So, basically the question is, *what is the difference between `IO.gets "Your name: " |> String.trim` and `IO.gets("Your name: ") |> String.trim`*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`|>` has a higher precedence than function calls in the Elixir parser, so this:

```
IO.gets "Your name: " |> String.trim
```

is exactly the same as:

```
IO.gets("Your name: " |> String.trim)
```

which is the same as:

```
IO.gets(String.trim("Your name: "))
```

As you already figured out, if you want to trim the result of `IO.gets`, you should do:

```
IO.gets("Your name: ") |> String.trim
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipe operator as you know is simply syntactic sugar very common in Elixir. 
Difference between

```
IO.gets "Your name: " |> String.trim
```

and

```
IO.gets("Your name: ") |> String.trim
```

is crucial.

In first one you pass to String.trim only the `"Your name: "`, and in second one you pass the result of `IO.gets("Your name: ")`. Using parenthesis when dealing with pipe operator is advised.